# how can i able to retrieve 379 from {"d":379}

Tags: regex, jmeter

I need to retrieve the 379 from a response {"d":379}.which regular expression should i use to retrieve the 379 only.

Comment: You shouldn't use regex at all. Thats JSON, parse it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even simpler. **Tested**. This should do it for your case.

```
/\d+/
```

**OR**

More precise

```
/\d+(?=})/
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) and access the desired property.

```js
let str = `{"d":379}`

console.log(JSON.parse(str)['d'])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have to go for the [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) - the relevant [regular expression](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html) would be something like:

```
"d":(\d+)
```

[image]

---

A better option would be going for [JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter-and-the-json-extractor) which provides possibility to perform correlation of JSON data using [JsonPath language](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#getting-started). The relevant JsonPath query would be as simple as:

```
$.d
```

[image]